# selectattr returns generator rows and cannot use results as a dict

Tags: ansible, jinja2

SOLUTION:
I Don't know what is the exact difference between `python -m pip install ansible`  or `apt install ansible` but when I installed `python -m pip ansible-core==2.10.4` it works fine.

---

I have CSV file which looks like:

```
id;env;credentials;path
1;tst;userA;/tmpA
2;dev;userB;/tmpB
3;dev;userB;/tmpC
4;acc;userB;/tmpD
5;prd;userC;/tmpE
```

I read this file using `read_csv` module and then I'm filtering using `selectattr`:

```yaml
  - name: Read CSV
    read_csv:
      path: "/tmp/example.csv"
      delimiter: ';'
    register: csv_output

  - name: Filter rows
    set_fact:
      new_fact: "{{ csv_output.list | selectattr('env', 'equalto', tst) }}"
```

In the past I was able to just use these results as a dict so for example:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ new_fact }}"

ok: [ansible_main] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "env": "tst",
            "credentials": "userA",
            "path": "/tmpA"
        }
    ]
}
```

but when I try to print `new_fact` on my local machine I see only generator:

```
ok: [ansible_main] => {
    "msg": "<generator object select_or_reject at 0x7f2e4e8847b0>"
}
```

and I cannot use `new_fact.credentials` variable... Do you know how can I fix it? I know I can add `| list` at the end of my filter but then I also cannot use `new_fact.credentials`

Details of my installation:

```
ansible 2.9.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/userA/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08) [GCC 9.3.0]
```

Comment: `selectattr` returns an Iterator, as documented: [`jinja-filters.selectattr(value: 't.Iterable[V]', *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) → 't.Iterator[V]'`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr). Because, obviously, if you pass `dev` as the env, you will end up with a list of two dictionaries. What you can do is `csv_output.list | selectattr('env', 'equalto', tst) | first` for the cases you are sure you will only get one element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding

> In the past I was able to just use these results as a dict ...

was it a much newer version of Ansible than v2.9.6?

> I know I can add `| list` at the end of my filter but then I also cannot user `new_fact.credential`s then

Since you will get a list too, it will be necessary to specify the element

```yaml
  - name: Filter rows
    set_fact:
      new_fact: "{{ csv_output.list | selectattr('env', 'contains', 'tst') | list }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ new_fact[0].credentials }}"
```

to loop over the result, or pickup one element only.

```yaml
  - name: Filter rows
    set_fact:
      new_fact: "{{ csv_output.list | selectattr('env', 'contains', 'tst') | first }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ new_fact.credentials }}"
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is a really good workaround for now but after all need to solve this issue, in the future it might cause different problems :( I installed the same versions of python and ansible and still there is a difference between selectattr. When I run ansible --version I see that jinja is in 2.10.1 version on the server (where problem with selecattr doesn't exist) but on my laptop I don't see any jinja version after I executed ansible --version command. pip3 freeze shows that Jinja2 is in 2.10.1 version so it is the same...